# How do I show my <p> containing my custom field ONLY if there is a set value on that custom field?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field

I am using the Custom Fields Plugin and have 2 custom fields assigned to my "products" custom post type.

Field 1. Price

Field 2 Discount Price

So this is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<p>Price: <?php the_field('price'); ?></p>
</div>
```

"Now this is what I am trying to achieve hypothetically"

```
 <div class="wrapper">
<?php if (the_field('discount'); )is set: ?>
    <p>Discount: <?php the_field('discount'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <p>Price: <?php the_field('price'); ?></p>
    </div><!--wrapper-end--> 


    <?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know if thats the best way to do what im trying to achieve but I am trying to only display a certain custom field and not the other depending on if one of them is set or not.

So this is really the logic thats giving me trouble:

```
if <?php the_field('discount'); ?> is set:
```

I have actually tried using :

```
<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("discount");

  if ( is_array($values) ): ?>

<p>Discount: <?php the_field('discount'); ?></p>

<?php else: ?>

<p>Price: <?php the_field('price'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

but did not seem to work when I had my price field set and not my discount field it just did not display anything. but if I had set a discount it would display.

Anyone have an idea?

**UPDATE**

So whenever I set my discount it would show, but when I did not have a discount my original price field didn't show. So that told me that there was something wrong with the else statement.

Never mind scratch that I I tried the code now the if statement is not working and only shows the else which is the price

Comment: Which Custom fields plugin are you using ACF or CFS ?

Comment: Advanced Custom Fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_field from ACF to check if the field is available and according to the [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) how you conditionally check if a field has contents.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php if (get_field('discount')) { ?>
        <p>Discount: <?php the_field('discount'); ?></p>
    <?php } else {  ?>
        <p>Price: <?php the_field('price'); ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
</div><!--wrapper-end-->
```

This should give you what you want.

Comment: Hmm so actually it did not work with isset and worked with is_array but only if I used your format on writing the if and else statement.. I really do not understand why the way I wrote my if and else statement did not output the else statement. Because if I set a discount it would show but if I take that out then the original price wouldn't show, so that was telling me something was wrong with my else statement. So i tried the way you wrote your format and it worked. Thank you for the help really appreciate it!

Comment: aaahhh scratch that apparently I tried changing up the way I write my if statement and now I only get the regular price and no special even with isset

Comment: Wow thanks for the update now that work! guess the conditional was wrong? and I needed to use `get_field`